# Android UnitCase android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven-3

all
I've recently created a unit test project in my main application. However, when I run the Unit Test I get this following error.

```
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File RuimockUnitTestTest from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f030000
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2391)
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2346)
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:944)
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
03-19 00:25:50.579: I/TestRunner(12465):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1892)
```

I've clean my project deleted the bin and gen file and still no hope. May anyone give some recommendations? Help is appreciated.

EDIT:
The unit test code is here, I have yet written the unit test :

```
public class ServerAPITest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<SplashScreen>{
SplashScreen mainActivity;
private Solo solo;

public ServerAPITest(){
    super(SplashScreen.class);
}


@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), (SplashScreen)getActivity());
    // Starts the MainActivity of the target application
    startActivity(new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), SplashScreen.class), null, null);

    // Getting a reference to the MainActivity of the target application
    mainActivity = (SplashScreen)getActivity();

}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();  
}

@SmallTest
public void testHello() throws Throwable{
     //TODO Test Function
 }
```

}

Comment: I have posted the code